# In second countable normal spaces, only countably many continuous maps are needed to separate every $(x,A)$ with $A$ closed and $x\not\in A$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a second countable normal space (where a normal space is not necessarily $T_4$).
> Then there is a countable collection of continuous maps $\{f_n:X\to[0,1]\}$ such that for any $x\in X$ and closed subset $A$ with $x\not\in A$, there is $f_k$ satisfying $f_k(x)=0$ and $f_k(A)=\{1\}$.

My attempt:

If we can somehow find a closed neighborhood of $x$ disjoint from $A$,
then the collections of maps can be obtained as follows.
For each pair $(U, V)$ of open sets in the countable base,
choose an $f$ that separates the closure of $U$ and the closure of $V$.
Since the base is countable, the collection of maps will also be countable.
But how do we find such a closed neighborhood?

Comment: If you start with a countable basis $\{ U_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of your topology, can't you just look at the pairs $(\overline{U_n}, \overline{X\setminus U_m})$ which are disjoint?

Comment: This is just plain false as stated.  Take the Sierpiński space $\{a,b\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$.  Then $\{b\}$ is closed, and $\overline{\{a\}}=\{a,b\}$, so there can be no such function separating $a$ from $\{b\}$.

Comment: What is the origin of your question?